# How to include package data with setuptools/distutils?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

When using setuptools, I can not get the installer to pull in any [`package_data`](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) files. Everything I've read says that the following is the correct way to do it. Can someone please advise?

```
setup(
   name='myapp',
   packages=find_packages(),
   package_data={
      'myapp': ['data/*.txt'],
   },
   include_package_data=True,
   zip_safe=False,
   install_requires=['distribute'],
)
```

where `myapp/data/` is the location of the data files.

Comment: I'm having the same problem... Manually specifying `data_files` solved the problem. But this is error-prone and does not "feel right" to me. Can someone verify that it is really *necessary* to duplicate the configuration in both `package_data` and `data_files`?

Comment: https://github.com/wimglenn/resources-example  Shows a modern setuptools project structure, which can correctly package data files into wheels and sdists using `pyproject.toml`. No `setup.py` file required.

Comment: for the love of it i can't get any of the answers below to work and the comments above would need a complete rewrite of many of my projects.

Answer (score 379, accepted):

I realize that this is an old question, but for people finding their way here via Google:  `package_data` is a low-down, [dirty lie](http://blog.codekills.net/2011/07/15/lies,-more-lies-and-python-packaging-documentation-on--package_data-/).  It is only used when building *binary* packages (`python setup.py bdist ...`) but *not* when building source packages (`python setup.py sdist ...`).  This is, of course, ridiculous -- one would expect that building a source distribution would result in a collection of files that could be sent to someone else to built the binary distribution.

In any case, using [`MANIFEST.in`](http://docs.python.org/2/distutils/sourcedist.html#manifest-template) will work *both* for binary and for source distributions.

Comment: I have been researching this issue for the past hour and have been trying many approaches. As you say, `package_data` works for `bdist` and not `sdist`. **However**, `MANIFEST.in` works for `sdist`, but *not* for `bdist`! Therefore, the best I have been able to come up with is to include both `package_data` and `MANIFEST.in` in order to accommodate both `bdist` and `sdist`.

Comment: I found another to support @WesleyBaugh. In http://stackoverflow.com/a/2969087/261718, Use `MANIFEST.in` for files you won't install, like documentation, and `package_data` for files you use that aren't Python code (like an image or template).

Comment: Ran into this today. I get that they might not want to change the behaviour, but it should *atleast* be mentioned in the docs.

Comment: I am using sdist, and had to include both `MANIFEST.in` *and* `package_data`.  It seems that `MANIFEST.in` controls what is included in the distribution, and package_data controls what subsequently gets copied into the site_packages dir during installation.  Confusingly, paths in `MANIFEST.in` are relative to the location of setup.py, and `package_data` is relative to the individual packages (e.g. modules) root.

Comment: "Changed in version 2.7: All the files that match package_data will be added to the MANIFEST file if no template is provided. See Specifying the files to distribute." [from distutils](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data). So, you'll only see the behaviour of files in `package_data` being automatically included in the ZIP *if you have no existing MANIFEST.in file*, and only if you're using 2.7+.

Comment: It is safe to use `package_data` with `setuptools`: http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files. Files are effectively included with both binary and source distributions, and can be accessed conveniently using the ResourceManager API described on the same page. See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/14211600/4716370.

Comment: Seriously, I feel like this ticket is a group therapy session for folks using setuptools and discovering just what a horrid place they have found themselves in life.

Comment: Thanks for this. For anyone else arriving here tearing their hair out about missing package data files: if you're distributing via a remote git repo, _make sure your data file is included in git_. Mine was ignored so it wasn't in the remote repo; had nothing to do with setuptools or manifests.

Comment: Using Python 3.6, `package_data` still doesn't work for me if I just run `python setup.py install`. Adding a `MANIFEST.in` solved the problem for me...

Comment: I found that sometimes the changes to `MANIFEST.in` doesn't take effect unless I delete the egg-info folder. These are SO DAMN confusing!

Comment: I am using a `MANIFEST.in` file and the `include_package_data=True` option to build a `sdist`.  The extra files only appear in my destination environment when I run `python setup.py install_lib` as mentioned [here](https://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/setuptools.html#using-setup-py)

Comment: Python 3.6 behavior I've seen: the `MANIFEST.in` specifies what files to include in the source distribution (sdist). `setup.py install` automatically adds the sdist python files to site-packages. But, the `include_package_data` flag controls whether non-python files distributed in the sdist AND existing in a package (directory with `__init__.py`) install to the site-packages location. So in order for non-python files to install with your code they need to a) be in the sdist (controlled by `MANIFEST.in`) and b) exist inside an installable python package. Otherwise you need to use `data_files`

Comment: There is also an argument that it is better to use `setuptools_scm` rather than a MANIFEST.in file - https://www.remarkablyrestrained.com/python-setuptools-manifest-in/

Comment: Python 3.8, setuptools 49.2.0 using `[options.package_data]` only for bdist. I was missing was that the `path/to/data/*` needed to be relative to the root of the package. Not `src/package/path/to/data/*` not `package/path/to/data/*`. Files would add automatically with `pip install .` but if I wanted to remove them (commenting out the `[options.package_data]` not an explicit deny), I would need to delete the `build` and `package.egg-info` files. The `package.egg-info/SOURCES.txt` shows the files when they are properly added. No `MANIFEST.in` created no `__init__.py`, although works with both.

Comment: This old but popular answer should be updated, because _"In any case, using MANIFEST.in will work both for binary and for source distributions."_ is **not** true. As @Wesley Baugh states in his popular comment, both ways are needed to get both sdist and bdist.

Answer (score 45):

I just had this same issue. The solution, was simply to remove `include_package_data=True`.

After [reading here](http://svn.python.org/projects/sandbox/trunk/setuptools/setuptools.txt), I realized that `include_package_data` aims to include files from **version control**, as opposed to merely "include package data" as the name implies. From the docs:

> The data files [of include_package_data] must be under CVS or Subversion control
>
> ...
>
> If you want finer-grained control over what files are included (for example, if
>   you have documentation files in your package directories and want to exclude
>   them from installation), then you can also use the `package_data` keyword.

Taking that argument out fixed it, which is coincidentally why it also worked when you switched to distutils, since it doesn't take that argument.

Comment: My experience differs, I had the same problem without including the `include_package_data=True` entry. Only solution for me is to add an entry in Manifest as suggested above. Mind you I was using setuptools, maybe your version works with 'distribute'?

Comment: Actual reason why removing `include_package_data` solves problem is further in the [original text](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files) – *If using the setuptools-specific `include_package_data` argument, files specified by `package_data` will not be automatically added to the manifest unless they are listed in the `MANIFEST.in` file.*

Comment: What is the use case of having `package_data` set to a non-empty list and specifying `include_package_data=False`? And why would you need to specify files twice in `MANIFEST.in` and `package_data`?

Answer (score 24):

Following @Joe 's recommendation to remove the `include_package_data=True` line also worked for me.

To elaborate a bit more, I have **no** `MANIFEST.in` file. I use Git and not CVS.

Repository takes this kind of shape:

```
/myrepo
    - .git/
    - setup.py
    - myproject
        - __init__.py
        - some_mod
            - __init__.py
            - animals.py
            - rocks.py
        - config
            - __init__.py
            - settings.py
            - other_settings.special
            - cool.huh
            - other_settings.xml
        - words
            - __init__.py
            word_set.txt
```

`setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import os.path

setup (
    name='myproject',
    version = "4.19",
    packages = find_packages(),  
    # package_dir={'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},  # didnt use this.
    package_data = {
        # If any package contains *.txt or *.rst files, include them:
        '': ['*.txt', '*.xml', '*.special', '*.huh'],
    },

#
    # Oddly enough, include_package_data=True prevented package_data from working.
    # include_package_data=True, # Commented out.
    data_files=[
#               ('bitmaps', ['bm/b1.gif', 'bm/b2.gif']),
        ('/opt/local/myproject/etc', ['myproject/config/settings.py', 'myproject/config/other_settings.special']),
        ('/opt/local/myproject/etc', [os.path.join('myproject/config', 'cool.huh')]),
#
        ('/opt/local/myproject/etc', [os.path.join('myproject/config', 'other_settings.xml')]),
        ('/opt/local/myproject/data', [os.path.join('myproject/words', 'word_set.txt')]),
    ],

    install_requires=[ 'jsonschema',
        'logging', ],

     entry_points = {
        'console_scripts': [
            # Blah...
        ], },
)
```

I run `python setup.py sdist` for a source distrib (haven't tried binary).

And when inside of a brand new virtual environment, I have a `myproject-4.19.tar.gz`, file, 
and I use

```
(venv) pip install ~/myproject-4.19.tar.gz
...
```

And other than everything getting installed to my virtual environment's `site-packages`, those special data files get installed to `/opt/local/myproject/data` and `/opt/local/myproject/etc`.

Answer (score 18):

`include_package_data=True` worked for me.

If you use git, remember to include `setuptools-git` in `install_requires`. Far less boring than having a `Manifest` or including all path in `package_data` ( in my case it's a django app with all kind of statics )

( pasted the comment I made, as [k3-rnc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute#comment56156410_7522250) mentioned it's actually helpful as is )

Answer (score 9):

### Using setup.cfg (setuptools ≥ 30.3.0)

Starting with setuptools 30.3.0 (released 2016-12-08), you can keep your `setup.py` very small and move the configuration to a `setup.cfg` file.  With this approach, you could put your package data in an `[options.package_data]` section:

```
[options.package_data]
* = *.txt, *.rst
hello = *.msg
```

In this case, your `setup.py` can be as short as:

```py
from setuptools import setup
setup()
```

For more information, see [configuring setup using setup.cfg files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#configuring-setup-using-setup-cfg-files).

There is [some talk of deprecating `setup.cfg`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56523197/974555) in favour of `pyproject.toml` as proposed in [PEP 518](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0518/), but this is still provisional as of 2020-02-21.

Comment: This answer neglects to mention MANIFEST file so I think it won't actually work with sdists. Only with wheels. You should mention that.

Comment: @wim I don't have enough understanding of MANIFEST, sdist, and wheels to answer that.  This worked for me using `pip install`.

Comment: That is because `pip install`, for a modern enough versions of pip, will first build a wheel and then install that. Still for many users this approach will silently fail to include package data. See the accepted answer and the comments under it for details about that. Using a `setup.cfg` is really just a different way of writing what the OP was already doing in `setup.py` in the question (by passing the `package_data` keyword argument in the call to `setup`), so I don't think this is particularly helpful as an answer *for this question*. It's not addressing the underlying problem at all.

Comment: @wim For what it's worth, I'm really happy to finally find an example with `setup.cfg`, for once. Somehow, the official package tutorials advices to use `setup.cfg` instead of `setup.py`, but then, most of the answers apply to `setup.py`. And those answers are already all over the place and mostly half-broken and unclear, so I don't need to add another unknown by trying to translate the options to `setup.cfg`. Sadly, this specific answer doesn't seem to work for my project. But it hopefully could help others.

Answer (score 7):

I found this post while stuck on the same problem.

My experience *contradicts* the experiences in the other answers.
`include_package_data=True` **does include the data in the
bdist!** The explanation in the `setuptools`
[documentation](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files)
lacks context and troubleshooting tips, but
`include_package_data` works as advertised.

My setup:

- Windows / Cygwin
- git version 2.21.0
- Python 3.8.1 Windows distribution
- `setuptools` v47.3.1
- `check-manifest` v0.42

Here is my how-to guide.

## How-to include package data

Here is the file structure for a project I published on PyPI.
(It installs the application in `__main__.py`).

```
├── LICENSE.md
├── MANIFEST.in
├── my_package
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __main__.py
│   └── _my_data          <---- folder with data
│       ├── consola.ttf   <---- data file
│       └── icon.png      <---- data file
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

### Starting point

Here is a generic starting point for the `setuptools.setup()` in
`setup.py`.

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    ...
)
```

`setuptools.find_packages()` includes all of my packages in the
distribution. My only package is `my_package`.

The sub-folder with my data, `_my_data`, is not considered a
package by Python because it does not contain an `__init__.py`,
and so `find_packages()` does not find it.

A solution often-cited, but **incorrect**, is to put an empty
`__init__.py` file in the `_my_data` folder.

This *does* make it a package, so it *does* include the folder
`_my_data` in the distribution. But the data files inside
`_my_data` are **not included**.

So making `_my_data` into a package **does not help**.

The solution is:

- the `sdist` already contains the data files
- add `include_package_data=True` to include the data files in the `bdist` as well

### Experiment (how to test the solution)

There are three steps to make this a repeatable experiment:

```sh
$ rm -fr build/ dist/ my_package.egg-info/
$ check-manifest
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

I will break these down step-by-step:

1. Clean out the old build:

```sh
$ rm -fr build/ dist/ my_package.egg-info/
```

2. Run `check-manifest` to be sure `MANIFEST.in` **matches** the
   Git index of files under version control:

```sh
$ check-manifest
```

If `MANIFEST.in` does not exist yet, **create it** from the Git
index of files under version control:

```sh
$ check-manifest --create
```

Here is the `MANIFEST.in` that is created:

```
include *.md
recursive-include my_package *.png
recursive-include my_package *.ttf
```

*There is no reason to manually edit this file.*

As long as everything that *should* be under version control is
under version control (i.e., is *part* of the Git index),
`check-manifest --create` does the right thing.

Note: files are **not** part of the Git index if they are either:

- ignored in a `.gitignore`
- excluded in a `.git/info/exclude`
- or simply *new* files that have not been *added* to the index yet

And if any files are under version control that *should not* be
under version control, `check-manifest` issues a warning and
specifies which files it recommends removing from the Git index.

3. Build:

```sh
$ python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Now inspect the `sdist` (source distribution) and `bdist_wheel`
(build distribution) to see if they include the data files.

Look at the contents of the `sdist` (only the relevant lines are
shown below):

```
$ tar --list -f dist/my_package-0.0.1a6.tar.gz
my_package-0.0.1a6/
...
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/__init__.py
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/__main__.py
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/_my_data/
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/_my_data/consola.ttf <-- yay!
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/_my_data/icon.png    <-- yay!
...
```

So the `sdist` already includes the data files because they are
listed in `MANIFEST.in`. There is nothing extra to do to include
the data files in the `sdist`.

Look at the contents of the `bdist` (it is a .zip file, parsed
with `zipfile.ZipFile`):

```sh
$ python check-whl.py
my_package/__init__.py
my_package/__main__.py
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/LICENSE.md
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/METADATA
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/WHEEL
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/entry_points.txt
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/top_level.txt
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/RECORD
```

Note: you need to create your own `check-whl.py` script to produce the
above output. It is just three lines:

```py
from zipfile import ZipFile
path = "dist/my_package-0.0.1a6-py3-none-any.whl" # <-- CHANGE
print('\n'.join(ZipFile(path).namelist()))
```

As expected, the `bdist` is missing the data files.

The `_my_data` folder is completely missing.

What if I create a `_my_data/__init__.py`? I repeat the
experiment and I find *the data files are still not there!* The
`_my_data/` folder *is included* but it does not contain the data
files!

### Solution

Contrary to the experience of others, this *does* work:

```py
setuptools.setup(
    ...
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True, # <-- adds data files to bdist
    ...
)
```

With the fix in place, redo the experiment:

```sh
$ rm -fr build/ dist/ my_package.egg-info/
$ check-manifest
$ python.exe setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
```

Make sure the `sdist` still has the data files:

```sh
$ tar --list -f dist/my_package-0.0.1a6.tar.gz
my_package-0.0.1a6/
...
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/__init__.py
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/__main__.py
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/_my_data/
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/_my_data/consola.ttf <-- yay!
my_package-0.0.1a6/my_package/_my_data/icon.png    <-- yay!
...
```

Look at the contents of the `bdist`:

```sh
$ python check-whl.py
my_package/__init__.py
my_package/__main__.py
my_package/_my_data/consola.ttf        <--- yay!
my_package/_my_data/icon.png           <--- yay!
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/LICENSE.md
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/METADATA
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/WHEEL
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/entry_points.txt
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/top_level.txt
my_package-0.0.1a6.dist-info/RECORD
```

### How **not** to test if data files are included

I recommend troubleshooting/testing using the approach outlined
above to inspect the `sdist` and `bdist`.

#### pip install in editable mode is not a valid test

Note: `pip install -e .` *does not* show if data files are
included in the `bdist`.

The symbolic link causes the installation to behave as if the
data files are included (because they already exist locally on
the developer's computer).

After `pip install my_package`, the data files are in the
virtual environment's `lib/site-packages/my_package/` folder,
using the exact same file structure shown above in the list of
the `whl` contents.

#### Publishing to TestPyPI is a slow way to test

Publishing to TestPyPI and then installing and looking in
`lib/site-packages/my_packages` is a valid test, but it is too
time-consuming.

Answer (score 6):

**Update**: This answer is old and the information is no longer valid. All setup.py configs should use `import setuptools`. I've added a more complete answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501350/64313

---

I solved this by switching to distutils. Looks like distribute is deprecated and/or broken.

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
   name='myapp',
   packages=['myapp'],
   package_data={
      'myapp': ['data/*.txt'],
   },
)
```

Comment: distribute isn't deprecated, it is _replacing_ distutils. I don't know why you were having the problem, but that's not the reason.

Comment: That was the response I got from IRC, so who do I believe? If you have a working example using distribute I would appreciate then.

Comment: clarification: distribute is meant to replace setuptools, both are built on top of distutils.  distutils itself will eventually be replaced by a new package, called "distutils2" in python2 and "packaging" in python3

Comment: Switching to distutils resolved my issue where `include_package_data=True` was not being honored. So with that setting you only need MANIFEST.in - no need to duplicate your file list in the `package_data` setting.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem for a couple of days but even this thread wasn't able to help me as everything was confusing. So I did my research and found the following solution:

> Basically in this case, you should do:
>
> ```
> from setuptools import setup
>
> setup(
>    name='myapp',
>    packages=['myapp'],
>    package_dir={'myapp':'myapp'}, # the one line where all the magic happens
>    package_data={
>       'myapp': ['data/*.txt'],
>    },
> )
> ```

[The full other stackoverflow answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53454049/how-to-include-a-text-file-in-a-python-installed-package/53474366#53474366)

Comment: Tried this, but still nothing gets copied.

Answer (score 4):

Ancient question and yet... package management of python really leaves a lot to be desired. So I had the use case of installing using pip locally to a specified directory and was surprised both package_data and data_files paths did not work out. I was not keen on adding yet another file to the repo so I ended up leveraging data_files and setup.py option --install-data; something like this

```
pip install . --install-option="--install-data=$PWD/package" -t package
```

Answer (score 4):

Like others in this thread, I'm more than a little surprised at the combination of longevity and *still* a lack of clarity, BUT the best answer for me was using `check-manifest` as recommended in the answer from @mike-gazes

So, using just a `setup.cfg` and no `setup.py` and additional text and python files required in the package, what worked for me was keeping this in setup.cfg:

```
[options]
packages = find:
include_package_data = true
```

and updating the `MANIFEST.in` based on the `check-manifest` output:

```
include *.in
include *.txt
include *.yml
include LICENSE
include tox.ini
recursive-include mypkg *.py
recursive-include mypkg *.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

Moving the folder containing the package data into to module folder solved the problem for me.

See this question: [MANIFEST.in ignored on "python setup.py install" - no data files installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596979/manifest-in-ignored-on-python-setup-py-install-no-data-files-installed)

Answer (score 3):

Just remove the line:

```
include_package_data=True,
```

from your setup script, and it will work fine. (Tested just now with latest setuptools.)

Comment: It's crazy but it works both with `sdist` and `bdist_wheel`, have you checked why?

Comment: I can indeed confirm that `sdist` ignores `package_data` when this is set.

Comment: At this point it's been months, but I seem to recall digging around in the code, getting lost twice, taking an EXTREMELY fine-toothed comb to the documentation, and gaining satisfaction. Apparently various sample scripts contain this flag and it causes no end of headaches.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with **Setuptools 62.3.0**, you can now use **recursive wildcards** (`"**"`) to include a (sub)directory recursively. This way you can include whole folders with all their folders and files in it.

For example, when using a `pyproject.toml` file, this is how you include two folders recursively:

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"ema_workbench.examples.data" = ["**"]
"ema_workbench.examples.models" = ["**"]
```

But you can also only include certain file-types, in a folder and all subfolders. If you want to include all markdown (`.md`) files for example:

```
[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"ema_workbench.examples.data" = ["**/*.md"]
```

It should also work when using `setup.py` or `setup.cfg`.

See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/3309 for the details.

Answer (score 2):

For a directory structure like:

```
foo/
├── foo
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── a.py
│   └── data.txt
└── setup.py
```

and `setup.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup


NAME = 'foo'
DESCRIPTION = 'Test library to check how setuptools works'
URL = 'https://none.com'
EMAIL = 'gzorp@bzorp.com'
AUTHOR = 'KT'
REQUIRES_PYTHON = '>=3.6.0'

setup(
    name=NAME,
    version='0.0.0',
    description=DESCRIPTION,
    author=AUTHOR,
    author_email=EMAIL,
    python_requires=REQUIRES_PYTHON,
    url=URL,
    license='MIT',
    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.6',
    ],
    packages=['foo'],
    package_data={'foo': ['data.txt']},
    include_package_data=True,
    install_requires=[],
    extras_require={},
    cmdclass={},
)
```

`python setup.py bdist_wheel` works.