# How include static files to setuptools - python package

Tags: python, package, setuptools

I want to include the `./static/data.txt` to `setuptools`, here is my code:

```
# setup.py
import os,glob
from setuptools import setup,find_packages

setup(
    name = "PotatoProject",
    version = "0.1.1",
    author = "Master Splinter",
    author_email = "splinter@initech.com",
    description = ("The potatoproject!"),
    url = 'http://www.google.com',
    license = "BSD",

    # adding packages
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'':'src'},

    # trying to add files...
    include_package_data = True,
    package_data = {
        '': ['*.txt'],
        '': ['static/*.txt'],
        'static': ['*.txt'],
    },

    scripts=['src/startPotato'],
    classifiers=[
        "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
        "Topic :: Utilities",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License",
    ],
)
```

The file system:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── src
    ├── distutils_setup.py
    ├── Potato
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── potatoData.txt
    │   └── printer.py
    ├── startPotato
    ├── static
    │   └── data.txt
    └── Tomato
        ├── big.py
        └── __init__.py
```

the output when running: `python setup.py sdist`

```
running sdist
running egg_info
creating src/PotatoProject.egg-info
writing src/PotatoProject.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to src/PotatoProject.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to src/PotatoProject.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
writing manifest file 'src/PotatoProject.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'src/PotatoProject.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'src/PotatoProject.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.txt

creating PotatoProject-0.1.1
creating PotatoProject-0.1.1/src
creating PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/Potato
creating PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/PotatoProject.egg-info
creating PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/Tomato
making hard links in PotatoProject-0.1.1...
hard linking setup.py -> PotatoProject-0.1.1
hard linking src/startPotato -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src
hard linking src/Potato/__init__.py -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/Potato
hard linking src/Potato/printer.py -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/Potato
hard linking src/PotatoProject.egg-info/PKG-INFO -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/PotatoProject.egg-info
hard linking src/PotatoProject.egg-info/SOURCES.txt -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/PotatoProject.egg-info
hard linking src/PotatoProject.egg-info/dependency_links.txt -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/PotatoProject.egg-info
hard linking src/PotatoProject.egg-info/top_level.txt -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/PotatoProject.egg-info
hard linking src/Tomato/__init__.py -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/Tomato
hard linking src/Tomato/big.py -> PotatoProject-0.1.1/src/Tomato
Writing PotatoProject-0.1.1/setup.cfg
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'PotatoProject-0.1.1' (and everything under it)
```

and no txt added! No `static/data.txt` nor `Potato/potatoData.txt`...

What am I missing?!

Answer (score 160, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, there are 2 ways to add the static files:

### 1 - include_package_data=True + MANIFEST.in

A `MANIFEST.in` file in the same directory of `setup.py` that looks like this:

```
include src/static/*
include src/Potato/*.txt
```

With `include_package_data = True` in `setup.py`.

### 2 - package_data in setup.py

```
package_data = {
    'static': ['*'],
    'Potato': ['*.txt']
}
```

Specify the files inside the `setup.py`.

---

#### Do not use both `include_package_data` and `package_data` in `setup.py`.

`include_package_data` will nullify the `package_data` information.

Official docs:
https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: Works! Apparently, MANIFEST.in picks out the which files to include *in addition* to what setup.py / distutils is smart enough to include by default.

Comment: Doing this plus adding the `include_package_data = True` above worked fro me. Both had to be done: The manifest file and the setup.py directive.

Comment: I just add "include *.txt". Works great thnx

Comment: It should be noted that anytime you specify `include_package_data=True`, you basically nullify the effect of `package_data`, and that's why setuptools expect you to include files in your `MANIFEST.in`. Use one of them (`package_data` vs  `include_package_data=True` +  `MANIFEST.in`) , not both.

Comment: Is it possible to write to the static directory during runtime?

Comment: Updated link: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: For those of you using the `setup.cfg` instead of `setup.py`, just add the `include_package_data = True` in the [options] section to have the build include anything listed in MANIFEST.in.

Comment: Please mention that you should use Manifest.in since its a better option https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distutils

Answer (score 31):

Include all files recursively:

```
recursive-include project_name/templates *
recursive-include project_name/static *
```

where `project_name` is a folder in the same line where you have `setup.py` file.

Comment: You may also want to include a single file with: `include funniest/data.json` for example

Comment: Where do you write this? In which file?

Answer (score 11):

According to the docs, there are [three ways](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files) to include package data files. You have two packages: Potato and Tomato. The static directory is not in either of those packages, so that is why your package_data dictionary in setup.py was not working. The manifest option requires that include_package_data is set to True in setup.py. Access non-package data files can be done the way found [here](http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#non-package-data-files).

Answer (score 11):

Use following

```
packages = ['.','templates','static','docs'],

package_data={'templates':['*'],'static':['*'],'docs':['*'],},
```

Comment: This might be too inclusive.

Answer (score 1):

Given a project structure like this:

```
.
├── setup.py
└── your_package
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── (code etc)
    └── static
        ├── a.txt
        ├── b.txt
        └── docs
            ├── a.rst
            └── b.rst
```

To recursively include all files under `static`, add the following in your `setup.py` (you do not need to add any `__init__.py` files inside of the `static` folder):

```
setup(
    ...
    package_data={"your_package": ["static/**/*"]},
)
```

The recursive glob `**/*` requires `setuptools>=62.3.0`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55432314/2111778 https://stackoverflow.com/a/64789489/2111778