# Struggling with making a Python module accessible via PyPi

Tags: python, pip, pypi

I wrote a simple Python interface for working with the Pushwoosh notification service a while back, which is at https://github.com/Astutech/Pushwoosh-Python-library and I've finally gotten around to publishing it so it can be installed using Pip. This is the first time I've published a Python library to PyPi and I'm in a bit of a muddle.

Trying to install it brings up the following error:

```
Collecting pushwoosh
  Using cached pushwoosh-1.0.0.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 20, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-5m3jj7uu/pushwoosh/setup.py", line 17, in <module>
        with open(path.join(here, 'DESCRIPTION.rst'), encoding='utf-8') as f:
      File "/usr/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 896, in open
        file = builtins.open(filename, mode, buffering)
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/pip-build-5m3jj7uu/pushwoosh/DESCRIPTION.rst'

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5m3jj7uu/pushwoosh
```

It looks like some kind of path related issue. I'm not sure that `pushwoosh.py` is in the correct location. But if I move it to `pushwoosh/pushwoosh.py`, and add a `pushwoosh/__init__.py` fileI then need to import it as follows:

```
from pushwoosh.pushwoosh import Pushwoosh
```

This is obviously not ideal. From the documentation I can't see where I've gone wrong. What directory layout should I be using?

EDIT: I have now resolved the issue with `DESCRIPTION.rst`, but unless I move the `pushwoosh.py` file to a `pushwoosh` folder and add an `__init__.py` file, installing the library doesn't actually install `pushwoosh.py` so it doesn't work. How can I amend it so I can import it like this?

```
from pushwoosh import Pushwoosh
```

Comment: You're probably not including `DESCRIPTION.rst` in your package. View: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package

Comment: @ThomasOrozco I've edited my answer as that part has been resolved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out in the end. It works if you put the file inside the `module_name` folder as `__init__.py`.

Answer (score 0):

You could've just put this into your __init__py file.

```
from pushwoosh import Pushwoosh
```

This lets you make the import like this without packing everything into the **init**.py file itself.

```
from pushwoosh import Pushwoosh
```

for a nice explanation check out this post http://mikegrouchy.com/blog/2012/05/be-pythonic-__init__py.html