# Where should I put project resources when doing pip install?

Tags: python, pip

I have a PyQt project where I create a GUI displaying some jpegs.

For comfortability when developing, the code would assume it is being run from the main project folder, so the jpegs path was relative to the main folder. Something like:

```
# Do something with "images/new.jpeg"
```

Now I would like to pip install the package and have an independant runnable.

I have no idea where is the correct place to put the jpegs, and how I should access them in the code.

I'm currently developing for Linux only (Ubuntu 16.04).

Any idea how I can get started? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [How include static files to setuptools - python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package)
 question to get started.