# including folder and files inside a Python package

Tags: python-3.x, python-packaging

I'm trying to make a python package and I have most of the things already setup by when I try to install the library from Github [here](https://github.com/CharmingMother/LeagueLib/tree/async), it installs everything except for the folder called `champs` and it's files

This is my File directory structure

```
LeagueYue
   champs
      -Lname_num.json
      -Lname_Uname.json
      -num_Uname.json
   -__init__.py
   -champion_files.py
   -external.py
   -match.py
   -rank.py
   -status.py
   -summoner.py
-requirements.txt
-setup.py
```

All the files are installed except for the folder and the files inside `champs`

Comment: I believe this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package) can solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you, it worked amazingly!
As for the bounty, I think you will have to post it as an "answer "and not a comment even though it is the answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How include static files to setuptools - python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package) answers:

There are 2 ways to add the static files:

### 1) Include_package_data=True + MANIFEST.in

A MANIFEST.in file in the same directory of setup.py, that looks like this:

```
include src/static/*
include src/Potato/*.txt
```

### 2) Package_data in setup.py

```
package_data = {
    'static': ['*'],
    'Potato': ['*.txt']
}
```

Specify the files inside the `setup.py.`

Answer (score 1):

Two of the files could probably be derived at runtime from num_Uname.json, but that's fine.

I do not yet see a `data_files` directive in https://github.com/CharmingMother/LeagueLib/blob/async/setup.py

Thomas Cokelaer suggests using an expression like

```
datafiles = [(datadir, list(glob.glob(os.path.join(datadir, '*'))))]
```

and then

```
setup(
    ...
    data_files = datafiles,
)
```

in http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/03/how-to-embedded-data-files-in-python-using-setuptools/

In your case this could be as simple as:

```
data_files = [('', ['champs/num_Uname.json'])],
```

Martin Thoma explains you should access them using `filepath = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, path)`
 in [How to read a (static) file from inside a Python package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6028000/how-to-read-a-static-file-from-inside-a-python-package/47972610#47972610)

When I Read The Fine [Manual](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files), this `setup.cfg` alternative surfaces:

```
[options.data_files]
...
data = data/img/logo.png, data/svg/icon.svg
```

suggesting a line like `. = champs/num_Uname.json` or `champs = num_Uname.json`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and insight, I wish I could also give you a bounty reward as well but  `Augusto A` has already answered before you