# How to include txt file within pip(pypi) module

Tags: python, module, pip, pypi

I created an pip module and installed the module in jupyter notebook.

There is one function that is not working because of the following.

I created a pip module and within this module I also have one text file with some information that is needed for the toolbox.

But when I create the pypi module, this txt file is not converted into the python wheel and now after installing this txt file cannot be found.

Is there a way to include a txt file within this module, or do I need to convert this txt file into another format (.csv?).

Comment: Share your function which isn't working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How include static files to setuptools - python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're probably calling `setuptools.setup` in your `setup.py` file to package your code. The logic by which setup decides which files to include in the wheel is, while it mostly works out of the box, [a little complicated](https://docs.python.org/3.7/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute).

In your case, it should be enough to add the file path of your `.csv` to a `package_data`-list:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    ...                                      # "name" and stuff
    packages=['mypkg'],                      # root folder of your package
    package_dir={'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},      # directory which contains the python code
    package_data={'mypkg': ['data/*.csv']},  # directory which contains your csvs
)
```

---

Concerning the [use `MANIFEST`, not `package_data`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/962190) argument the doc pages talk about, since you use `wheel` to build the package you should be fine. `wheel` uses bdist by default, which works well with `package_data`.