# How to use static files included with setuptools?

Tags: python, setuptools

I want to locally install a package from one project in another project. I am able to install the package and import the function I want to call. The function loads a pickle file. When I call the function it fails with a `FileNoutFoundError`.

I have followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11848281/5320601) and use `include_package_data=True` and `MANIFEST.in` but that does not resolve my error.

I have a simple project structured like this:

```
.
├── example_pkg
│   ├── foobar.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── pickle_files
│       └── test.p
├── MANIFEST.in
├── __pycache__
└── setup.py
```

`MANIFEST.in` content:

```
include example_pkg/pickle_files/*
```

`foobar.py`:

```
import os
import pickle


def out():
    with open(os.path.join("pickle_files", "test.p"), "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump({"hello": "world"}, f)


def f_in():
    with open(os.path.join("pickle_files", "test.p"), "rb") as f:
        d = pickle.load(f)
    print(d["hello"])
```

`test.p` is created by calling `out()`. I do not want to call it after installing the package in another project to create the file again, it is just here to demonstrate where the file comes from.

`setup.py` looks like this:

```
import setuptools

setuptools.setup(
    name="example-pkg-foo",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
)
```

`init.py` is blank.

I then run `python setup.py sdist` which creates a folder `dist` with a file `example-pkg-foo-0.0.1.tar.gz` in it. When I manually inspect this tarball I can see that `example_pkg/pickle_files/test.p` exists.

--- Everything above this line is part of project A. Everything below is part of project B. ---

I then copy+paste the tarball to my other project (project B) and run `pip install example*`. The package is then installed in my project's (project B) virtual environment.

Then I run the following script using the virtual environment of project B:

```
from example_pkg.foobar import f_in

f_in()
```

I can import the package and call the function. However, it fails with

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/madjura/PycharmProjects/package_experiment/foo.py", line 3, in <module>
    f_in()
  File "/home/madjura/PycharmProjects/package_experiment/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/example_pkg/foobar.py", line 11, in f_in
    with open(os.path.join("pickle_files", "test.p"), "rb") as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pickle_files/test.p'
```

When I inspect the venv (of project B) I can see that the file was included in the installation:

```
.
└── site-packages
    ├── example_pkg
    │   ├── foobar.py
    │   ├── __init__.py
    │   ├── pickle_files
    │   │   └── test.p  <------ it is included in the venv
    │   └── __pycache__
    │       ├── foobar.cpython-37.pyc
    │       └── __init__.cpython-37.pyc
    └── example_pkg_foo-0.0.1-py3.7.egg-info
        ├── dependency_links.txt
        ├── installed-files.txt
        ├── PKG-INFO
        ├── SOURCES.txt
        └── top_level.txt
```

My Python version is 3.7.3. I want to install a package with a pickle file locally in another project, without creating a new pickle file. I want to use the one that already exists. How can I fix the `FileNotFoundError` when I call `f_in()`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+path+installed+files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change `foobar.py` to:

```py
import os
import pickle


def out():
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "pickle_files", "test.p"), "wb") as f:
        pickle.dump({"hello": "world"}, f)


def f_in():
    with open(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "pickle_files", "test.p"), "rb") as f:
        d = pickle.load(f)
    print(d["hello"])
```

when you launch it from other place you have different starting point for decoding path.