# setuptools find_packages() unable to locate files in the nested directories

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

I'm currently trying to upload a python module to PyPi. My `setup.py` file is currently coded as below to locate the packages.

**setup.py** (simplified)

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
   # other specifications
   packages=find_packages()
)
```

However, the package I'm trying to upload has the following directory structure.

```
main_folder
|
|--nest_folder
|  |
|  |--nested.json
|  |--nested.py
|  |--nested.txt
|
|---__init__.py
|---other.py
```

With my setup file, it's able to locate `__init__.py` and `other.py` but is unable to find any of the files in the `nested_foler`. In other words, it only builds those two files, leaving the files in the nested folder out of the module's build.

Is there a way to build the entire `main_folder` into a module and upload this to PyPi?

Comment: I could be wrong, but perhaps add a __init__.py in ```nest_folder```?

Comment: no you are right. adding `__init__,py` worked partially. It now recognizes the python files in the nested directory but it doesn't seem to grab the json or txt files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11848030/7976758