# Can I automatically put some plain text files in a directory via pip install besides the program to be installed?

Tags: setuptools, distutils

I have written a program consisting of a few .py-scripts, which I am able to successfully make into one package via wheel and bdist and upload it to pypi.org via twine, from where I can download and install it via "pip install".
I have 3 or 4 configuration-files, that are kept in .txt-format and my program optionally uses those configuration-files to configure itself when it starts.
Is there a way to somehow integrate those .txt-files into that package and upload it, so when someone does "pip install", he not only installs the programm, but automatically also gets those 3 .txt-files into a certain directory?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How include static files to setuptools - python package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+%22package_data%22