# python setup.py with root folder directories

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a python project folder with a setup.py in below structure.

```
root
|_app
   |__main.py__
   |__init.py__
   |_ other.py files
|_inputs
   |_.py files
|_logger
   |_.py files
|_setup.py
```

I need to package all these folders into one directory when build the list in following format.

```
app
|_main, init and other py files
|_logger
|_inputs
```

my setup file is currently looks like,

```
from setuptools import setup
import os

setup(name='app',
      version=os.environ['BUILD_NUMBER'],
      description='sol',
      author='codebot',
      packages=['app',
                'app.loaders',
                'app.data',
                'app.config',
                'inputs',
                'logger'
                ],
      entry_points={
          'group_1': 'run=app.__main__:main'
      })
```

But with this I can't see the inputs and logging(which contains only .py files) in the package folder once installed. How may I fix this with setup.py? I was thinking of whether there is a way to copy folders using setup.py. But no luck yet.

Comment: Why not have the folders under `_app` to begin with?

Comment: then I have to change all the import statements of the code. which is not possible atm

Comment: Are you trying to package static files?Can this help you? <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package>

Comment: no. all folders have .py files only