# txt.gz file isn't in my published pypi package

Tags: python, continuous-integration, pypi

I have a `.txt.gz` in my repo which should part of a pypi package. When I publish a new pypi release and inspect the installed pacakge in my environment I can see that file is not part of the pacakge. Why isn't this file in the package?

Comment: Have you added it to your setup.py? [Adding static files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11848030/how-include-static-files-to-setuptools-python-package)

Comment: Thanks for you quick response @InsertCheesyLine. This is the answer I needed! Thx!

Comment: I ended up adding a MANIFEST.in file in my repo