# Python: Why setuptools doesn't include my package data?

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils

Today I created a setup.py-file and found one working script and two none working scenarios.
In the two non working scenarios the `package_data` after is missing in the build. I created the build with *`python setup.py sdist`*.

## Why scenario 2 and 3 don't include my package data?

## Scenario 1 works:

```
import os 
from distutils.core import setup

def find_packages(path):
    package_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), path)
    packages = []
    for f in os.walk(package_path):

    directory_name = f[0]

    if directory_name.endswith('egg-info') or directory_name.endswith('path'):
        continue

    directory_name = directory_name.replace(package_path, '').replace('/', '.').strip()

    if not len(directory_name):
        continue

    if directory_name.startswith('.'):
        directory_name = directory_name.replace('.', '', 1)

    packages.append(directory_name)

return packages

setup (
    name = 'mypkg',
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},
    include_package_data = True,
    package_data = {
        '': ['*.txt'],
        'mypkg': ['data/*.dat'],
    }
)
```

## Scenario 2, doesn't work:

```
from setuptools import setup #, find_packages
from setuptools.command import sdist
setup (
    name = 'mypkg',
    packages = ['mypkg'],
    package_dir = {'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},
    include_package_data = True,
    package_data = {
        '': ['*.txt'],
        'mypkg': ['data/*.dat'],
    }
)
```

## Scenario 3 doesn't work either:

```
from setuptools import find_packages
from setuptools.command import sdist
setup (
    name = 'mypkg',
    packages = find_packages('src'),
    package_dir = {'mypkg': 'src/mypkg'},
    include_package_data = True,
    package_data = {
        '': ['*.txt'],
        'mypkg': ['data/*.dat'],
    }
)
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, the problem wasn't in setup.py but the missing MANIFEST.in, which needs to also declare package data.

Comment: thats not true, if package_data is declared correctly it goes into Manifest automatically.

Comment: @marscher, `package data` doesnot work in source distributions.. you need MANIFEST.in .. check http://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/1327005 so tsg is right

Comment: Yes you would need it both in setup.py package_data and MANIFEST.in

Answer (score 4):

you can not use glob syntax directly in package_data declaration.

but you can declare a variable containing this data before passing it to setup function:

```
from glob import glob

data = glob('data/*.dat')
txt_files = glob('*.txt')

...

setup(...
package_data = {
    '': txt_files,
    'mypkg': data,
}
...
```

Comment: Huh. After all my work mucking around with MANIFESTS, this appears to actually be the correct answer (at least in setuptools).

Comment: This is not correct, setuptools uses glob by default: package_data = {'': ['*.dat']}