# How do I list the files inside a python wheel?

Tags: python, package, python-wheel, python-packaging

I'm poking around the various options to `setup.py` for including non-python files, and they're somewhat less than intuitive. I'd like to be able to check the package generated by `bdist_wheel` to see what's actually in it--not so much to make sure that it will work (that's what tests are for) but to see the effects of the options I've set.

How do I list the files contained in a `.whl`?

Comment: Pretty sure [it's a zip file](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/wheel).

Comment: Regarding the "not so much to make sure that it will work": some checklist items are unusual subjects for testing, for example making sure that any additional license files accompanying external C libraries that are included in compiled form within the wheel. These items are best checked by listing the wheel's contents. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24347450/how-do-you-add-additional-files-to-a-wheel

Answer (score 98, accepted):

You can take the wheel file change the extension to `.zip` and then extract the contents like any other zip file.

from [PEP 427](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/)

> A wheel is a ZIP-format archive with a specially formatted file name
> and the `.whl` extension.

##### Example

the [Django python package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Django/) has a wheel file. Try [Django-1.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl](https://pypi.python.org/packages/py2.py3/D/Django/Django-1.8.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=3a586ed7da0715ea65ec94a9b1ff2d87) as an example. Their package contains non-python files if you wanted to see where they end up being stored in the archive.

##### Code

The following code works correctly using `python2` and `python3`. It will list the files in any wheel package. I use the `pep8` wheel package as an example, whose wheel can be downloaded with `pip download --no-deps pep8==1.7.0`.

```py
import pprint
from zipfile import ZipFile

path = 'pep8-1.7.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl'
names = ZipFile(path).namelist()
pprint.pprint(names)
```

##### Output

```py
['pep8.py',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/DESCRIPTION.rst',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/entry_points.txt',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/metadata.json',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/namespace_packages.txt',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/top_level.txt',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/WHEEL',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/METADATA',
 'pep8-1.7.0.dist-info/RECORD']
```

Answer (score 60):

```sh
unzip -l dist/*.whl
```

([credit](https://superuser.com/a/216619/199930))

Since a [wheel is](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0427/#abstract) a [ZIP file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_(file_format)), [`unzip`](http://infozip.sourceforge.net/) works. Tab completion for the file name won't work, unless the extension is renamed to `zip`. The `from zipfile import ZipFile` approach assumes only the presence of Python in the system, but a one-liner in the shell is more practical.

---

Another option is to view the contents of the wheel file using [`vim`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)). This can be done by first adding to the file `~/.vimrc` the line:

```
au BufReadCmd *.whl call zip#Browse(expand("<amatch>"))
```

([`vimrc`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#vimrc) and [`BufReadCmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/autocmd.html#BufReadCmd) documentation) and then using:

```sh
vim filename.whl
```

within `vim`, files can be entered by pressing the key `ENTER`, and exited by typing `:q`. `vim` can be exited by typing `:q` when viewing the directory listing within the wheel file.

Answer (score 21):

One could use Python's own [*`zipfile`* module and CLI](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#command-line-interface) to list the files in a *wheel* (or any other *zip* file):

```
python -m zipfile --list path/to/my-wheel-file.whl
```

Or to extract:

```
python -m zipfile --extract path/to/my-wheel-file.whl path/to/output/directory
```

There is also [*`tarfile`*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) and its [*CLI*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#command-line-interface). This can be used for *source distributions* (*sdist*) for example.

```
python -m tarfile --list path/to/my-sdist-file.tar.gz
```

Comment: this is the answer when you're inside a docker image with no unzip and no vi :D

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the answers, any `.whl` file can be extracted using unzip or by right clicking on the file and extracting using the `Extract Here` graphical interface in Ubuntu/Debian systems.

After extracting, one can inspect the source code of `.py` files and the contents of metadata files which will be located in `library-name-with-version.dist-info` directory. However, the source code of shared object (`.so`) files can not be inspected since that's a binary file.

---

Another handy option would be to use the [**wheel-inspect**](https://pypi.org/project/wheel-inspect/) package which is specifically built for this purpose. The description of the package is stated as:

> `wheel-inspect` examines Python wheel files & `*.dist-info` directories and outputs various information about their contents as **JSON-serializable** objects.

A sample command is:

```
$ wheel2json some_lib_wheel_file.whl
```

That would spit out the contents in a json file. If this json file needs to be stored locally, then redirect the output to a json file.

```
$ wheel2json some_lib_wheel_file.whl > some_lib.json
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple way (in Windows) is to append a `.zip` extension to the end of the filename. For example:

```
somepackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl --> somepackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl.zip
```

Then just open the file with Windows file explorer and see what files are there.  You should change the name back if you need to still use the original file.

Comment: This answer adds nothing new compared to other already existing answers.

Comment: The purpose is that you don’t always need Python to solve a simple problem. Just unzip it and look with with Win Explorer

Comment: Exactly this scenario is already described in the first sentence of the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

`whl` file is just a zip archive, so you can use `tar` to interact with it:

list contents:

```
tar -tf dist/somepackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl
```

print a particular file's contents into the stdout (eg. `somepackage-1.0.0.dist_info/METADATA`)

```
tar -Oxf dist/somepackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl somepackage-1.0.0.dist_info/METADATA
```

Comment: Not true. Wheel is a Zip archive: https://peps.python.org/pep-0427/#abstract -- And then, this answer adds nothing new compared to already existing answers.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the format being zip (and not tar). I. would argue that an example of how to use a _built in shell tools_ to inspect your package is valuable (would have been for me).

Comment: `python -m zipfile --list dist/somepackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl` and `unzip -l dist/somepackage-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl` are already mentioned in other answers.