# What packages are required on Alpine to run numpy after build

Tags: python, linux, numpy, containers, alpine-linux

I am planning to build NumPy on Alpine Linux container. To do so I will first install the following packages.

`apk add --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies musl-dev linux-headers g++`

My question is, does NumPy rely on these packages (i.e. `musl-dev linux-headers g++`) to run or is it just for the build, can I just delete them after build? ( i.e. `apk del build-dependencies` ) Likewise same question for pandas which needs more of these build dependencies.

Comment: If you build libraries statically, you no longer need the build requirements after the build has completed successfully. This is not the case with dynamic libs.

Comment: How do i know if a lib is dynamic or not

Comment: Static libraries on Linux end with `.a`, while dynamic libraries end with `.so`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help, do you know how to get this information in Linux Alpine

Comment: There are `manylinux` wheels for NumPy [available from PyPI](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/#files). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/32923952/1426065 for info on unzipping wheels and seeing what files are contained within them. You may need to unzip the wheel and then unzip the `.egg` file inside, if it contains one.

Comment: I would assume that the `manylinux` wheels have statically-linked libraries in them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Building numpy from source [numpy-1.21.5.zip](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/a8/a924a09492bdfee8c2ec3094d0a13f2799800b4fdc9c890738aeeb12c72e/numpy-1.21.5.zip) in alpine:

```sh
apk add python3 python3-dev cython py3-setuptools gcc gfortran g++
unzip numpy-1.21.5.zip
cd numpy-1.21.5
python3 setup.py build
python3 setup.py install
```

After this, the only runtime requirements are of course python and `libc.musl-x86_64.so.1` which is part of `musl`. And it is a base package already required by python3.

```
~ # find /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.21.5-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/ -name "*.so" -print -exec sh -c 'readelf -d {} | grep NEEDED' \;
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.21.5-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_tests.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-musl.so
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.musl-x86_64.so.1]
/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.21.5-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-musl.so
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.musl-x86_64.so.1]
...
```

**Edit**:
In order to make numpy faster, you need [openblas](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86/openblas) (and openblas-dev at build time).

```
apk add openblas-dev
```

At runtime, numpy shared libraries will link to `libopenblas.so.3` (part of openblas)

```
~ # readelf -d /usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy-1.21.5-py3.9-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-musl.so

Dynamic section at offset 0x40bb40 contains 20 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libopenblas.so.3]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.musl-x86_64.so.1]
...
```