# why doesn't include resource files as expected?

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
LONGDOC = """
To be completed
"""

PACKAGES = find_packages()

def setup_package():

    setup(name='wbn',
          version='3.10',
          description='knowledge matcher',
          long_description=LONGDOC,
          packages=PACKAGES
    )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    setup_package()
```

When I do:

```
pip install .
```

I can see that in my virtual environment's site-packages directory 'wbn', all python source codes are installed correctly, but all resource files are not. So I added this file to MANIFEST.in for example:

```
recursive-include nl/cli *.yml
```

I hope this will add all *.yml files recursively to the 'wbn' library's installation directory, but it didn't.

What's wrong with my packaging?

Comment: The `MANIFEST.in` file is used to include files in the *source* dist, e.g. the `.tar.gz` file created by the `sdist` argument.  The `package_data` or `data_files` arguments are used to include the *build’s* resource files … these are the files installed and bundled in via the `build` or `bdist_wheel` arguments.

Comment: Where did you add that line?  How would setuptools know that it's supposed to add those files?

Comment: Further to my comment above, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49501350/6340496) might be of use. (I’ve bookmarked it and refer to it time after time.)

Comment: I added it to the file MANIFEST.in.

Comment: @S3DEV So probably I should add a 'package_data' to setup function. I had thought package_data only add python files.

Comment: And after @S3DEV's comment, you now know that was not the right place to put it.  The file names need to be passed in a `data_files` argument.

Comment: @TimRoberts Should it be in 'data_files' or 'package_data' arguments?  Either one is ok?

Comment: The documentation should be helpful in making that decision.  https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+static+files

Answer (score 0):

you would need both MANIFEST.in for packaging (source distribtions) and a package_data dictionary as setup metadata.

https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/datafiles.html