# Including external binaries in python package

Tags: python, setup.py

I have a python module that is basically a big wrapper (which does lots more stuff besides) for an external binary (non python). I would like to include the binaries (1 binary for osx, 1 for linux) along with my code. I currently have the following in my setup.py:

```
package_data={'packagename': ['lib/app-osx/*', 'lib/app-linux/*', 'lib/*.awk']},
```

and the files are located at:

```
/packagename
 /lib
  script.awk
  /app-osx/
    app
  /app-linux
    app
```

I can't seem to find where they are installed, if they are at all? Is there a convention for this? I obviously can't use dependencies for this :(

And then, what's the best way of finding their location within the python script?

Thanks

Comment: Use the [resource manager API](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#basic-resource-access) to access resources from your Egg. You'll probably want to use [`resource_filename`](http://peak.telecommunity.com/DevCenter/PkgResources#resource-extraction) if you need the filesystem path to your binaries. Someting like `import pkg_resources; path = pkg_resources.resource_filename('packagename', 'foo.bin')` (untested).

Comment: Thanks. Is my setup.py written correctly?

Comment: From what I can tell, yes, the declaration of package resources seems to be correct.

Comment: If it doesn't work, try something like `resource_stream()` first - it should tell you exactly what in what path it was looking for the resource (`resource_filename` just builds the path, whether that resource exists or not).

Comment: There seems to be a caveat with `package_data` though, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/1599111).

Comment: Thanks for the help, Lukas. I'm only sorry I can't accept one as the accepted answer!

Comment: You're welcome, don't worry about it :) I'm just a bit too tired right now to write up a half-decent answer (setuptools stuff always takes quite a bit of time to test, and I don't like writing untested answers). Maybe I'll get around to it tomorrow.

Comment: Ah, I just realised something. My module isn't being installed as an egg, it's installing as Module.egg-info and Module/ in site-packages.. I can't use pkg_resources with non-egg installations?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/56985/discussion-between-garethprice-and-lukas-graf).

Comment: @GarethPrice You guys seemed to figure this out in chat. Shame that the rest of us who land on this question were abandoned, though. Care to write an answer describing your complete solution, and why each piece is necessary? You can accept it, and others can upvote.

Comment: Sure @JonathonReinhart, I've added the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Jonathon's prompting, I went through the chat and found the solution that Lukas provided me. The solution was simply to add the following to the setup.py:

```
zip_safe=False
```

Comment: Thanks! If you provide your full `setup.py`, and explain why `zip_safe=False` fixed your problem, I will happily up-vote this question and answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think [MANIFEST.in](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/) can solve all problems with additional files attached to the python package.

```
recursive-include lib/app-osx/*
recursive-include lib/app-linux/*
recursive-include lib/*.awk
```