# Including data files in python build and install

Tags: python, manifest, setup.py

I have been fiddling with the `MANIFEST.IN` file and `setup` parameters `package_data` and `data_files` (both `distutils` and `setuptools`) for hours, and I can't figure out how to include data files when building and installing a python package. I managed to get some results when I run `python setup.py sdist`, but not with `python setup.py install --user` and not with `pip install . --user`.

Let's consider the following simple package structure:

```
mypackage/
    mymodule/
        __init__.py
        gui.py
    data/
        icons/
            icon1.png
    MANIFEST.in
    setup.py
```

What should I put in `setup.py` and `MANIFEST.in` to have `data/icons/icon1.png` copied in my build and install directories?

I would prefer an opt-in solution (declare all files that must be included).

EDIT:

It turns out I can make it work when I use `python setup.py install --user`, using `data_files` parameter in `setup()`. The problem is with `pip install . --user`, which is the preffered way of installing my software. I find this strange, I always thought `pip install` was roughly doing the same thing as `python setup.py install`.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute). Basically, MANIFEST.in should be used for building sdists or bdists, and setuptools' `include_package_data` or similar directives only works for bdists. If you're going to distribute as both, you can use both solutions. Note that `data_files` is entirely different and is for distributing data files from the package onto the target system at install time (and requires installing from an sdist, not a wheel).

Comment: Thanks, but distributing is not the problem. The problem is installing.
I found some clues here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/Distutils/Cookbook/InstallDataScattered?action=show&redirect=DistutilsInstallDataScattered  

A couple of examples: https://github.com/kif/pyFAI/blob/master/setup.py#L312 
https://github.com/vasole/pymca/blob/master/setup.py#L544



But I can't believe installing icons is such a complex problem.

Comment: Another dirty fix would be to declare my data folders as subpackages and add empty __init__.py in each directory, but that's extremely dirty.

Comment: I have never had a problem with the install, as long as everything is included in the sdist. Have you checked the egg info to ensure that all of your files are actually being included? Also, it can be useful to totally wipe out any egg-info and build directories prior to rebuilding. Sometimes their being there can mess up inclusion of new files.

Comment: It turns out I can make it work when I use ``python setup.py install --user``. The problem is with ``pip install . --user``, which is the preffered way of installing my software.

I find this strange, I always thought ``pip install`` was roughly doing the same thing as ``python setup.py install``.

Comment: More fun facts: it works with ``pip install`` if I import ``install_data`` from ``distutils.command.install_data`` rather than from ``setuptools.command.install_data``