# can I make a virtualenv into an egg

Tags: python, virtualenv, egg

I can make a python egg using setuptools: `python setup.py bdist_egg`. In theory, I should be able to do this for every installed package with a `setup.py` file. Is it possible to encapsulate an entire `virtualenv` virtual python environment to a python egg?

Comment: What is the file structure layout of your project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I specifically **needed** to package an arbitrary number of Python packages *into one `.egg`*, because the system that I was using accepted *only* eggs and each of them needed to be listed separately which became very unwieldly when the number of needed packages changes.

An *.egg* file is just a *.zip* with a metadata folder named `EGG-INFO` *and* a version number in its name. You could basically `cd lib/python-x.y/site-packages`, then `zip -r spaghetti-0.0.1.egg` to zip the contents into into *`spaghetti-0.0.1.egg`* file, but you do need metadata

If you're lucky and you do not have packages that use entrypoints or other such advanced features, you can just create a directory named `EGG-INFO` in the `site-packages` with the following files in it:

```
dependency_links.txt
entry_points.txt
not-zip-safe
PKG-INFO
requires.txt
top_level.txt
```

all of them **empty** besides `PKG-INFO` that contains the following contents

```
Metadata-Version: 1.1
Name: spaghetti
Version: 0.0.1
```

*and* `top_level.txt` containing the **all** top-level package names from your virtualenv, one per line, i.e. if you've installed the namespace package [`zope.component`](https://pypi.org/project/zope.component/) and `sqlalchemy`, your `top_level.txt` should have

```
zope
sqlalchemy
```

---

Of course things are not always this simple. For namespace packages on Python 2.7 (such is the case with `zope.component`) there are some magic `.pth` entries. For these you need to create empty `__init__.py`s in the packages, or alternatively list them in the `EGG-INFO/namespace_packages.txt`;  in the case of `zope.component`, the `zope` is a namespace package with no `__init__.py`, so `EGG-INFO` should have `namespace_packages.txt` with one line, `zope`. However namespace packaging in Python 3 should work as-is without this intermediate step.

<s>Likewise if you need to use entrypoints, you need to concatenate the entrypoints.txt from the egg infos from all packages into the `entrypoints.txt` of your egg.</s>

**Correction:** you cannot do entry points in this fashion, not without any serious hacks anyway. The distribution name, in this case `spaghetti`, would be used for all entry points instead of the package name. There is no direct way of circumventing this.

---

Finally, `wheel` indeed can be considered a format that is superior to `egg` but they're not compatible and if you *can* you should use `wheel` for packaging the virtual environment. But if a system specifically expects to have a file in the old `.egg` file format it wouldn't work with wheel. Furthermore, an `.egg` sometimes needs not be *installed*, it can be used from `PYTHON_PATH` as it is...

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't do this for several reasons

Even if you could manage to do this, it wouldn't work as you'd expect.  If the user already had one of the packages inside your egg installed, they would clash, because python eggs don't add additional namespaces.

Also, python eggs are kind of on their way out.  If you want to create a binary distribution, you should use the newer python `wheels`.

If you have a project with dependencies, just declare those dependencies in your `setup.py` and pip will handle installing them.  If you have some dependencies that don't exist on PyPi, or you need a very specific legacy version of a package, just include those packages as a subpackage in your package.

```
/my_package
    __init__.py
    /libs
        __init__.py
        /non_pypi_package
        /legacy_package
```

And then in your code, instead of importing them as

```
import non_pypy_package
```

you would use

```
from my_package.libs import non_pypi_package
```

Comment: The way I am using eggs I am able to store a compiled C/Fortran package which is a dependency of the python package. Is there a way I can still do this?

Comment: You can do it using the [`package_data`](https://docs.python.org/2/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-package-data) argument to the `setup` function.  If you provide more information about how your project is structured, I can add the exact commands to include them.

Comment: I'm not sure how I can use package_data in the way you're describing. This previous answer was not as hopeful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/3474956. It does not look like there is any modern equivalent to python eggs.

Comment: Wheels are the modern equivalent of eggs.