# FileNotFoundError after python setup.py install (not after develop!)

Tags: python, installation, setuptools, file-not-found

I have a python project with the following structure:

```
src/
  main.py
  example.txt
setup.py
```

After installation, I should be able to call `myprogramm -name bla` and it should create a new folder `bla` and copy `example.txt` inside.

When installing the program with `python setup.py develop` (inside a virtualenv) everything works fine and as expected.
However, when using `python setup.py install`, I get a `FileNotFoundError` when executing the command as Python cannot find `example.txt`.

Why doesn't it copy `example.txt` to the correct location when installing with `python setup.py install`? How can I fix the problem? Do I need to include `example.txt` explicitly in my `setup.py` somehow?

Comment: Show your setup.py

Comment: *Do I need to include example.txt explicitly in my setup.py somehow?* Yes. See [Including Data Files](https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#including-data-files).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Including a `MANIFEST.in` **and** adding `include_package_data=True` in my `setup.py` solved my problem.

Apparently, `package_data` does not behave how you would expect: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/2745116