# How can I tell 'setup.py' to include files from my root directory for the built distribution?

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, pypi

I have a typical project structure that looks like this:

```
/project/ 
  README.md
  CONTRIBUTING.md
  LICENSE
  setup.py
  requirements.txt
  project/
    some_project_file
  docs/
    some_docs_file
  tests/
    some_tests_file
```

When running `python setup.py sdist bdisst_wheel`, the resulting distribution in the created 'dist' folder contains everything but the 'CONTRIBUTING', 'LICENSE', and 'requirements.txt' files. Is it possible to have these files from my root directory included in the built distribution?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bsetuptools%5D+include+data+files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a MANIFEST.in file with the content like:

```
include LICENSE
include CONTRIBUTING.md
include requirements.txt
```

Comment: this works for source distribution; not for binary distributions though

Comment: @ChaitanyaBapat: Binary distributions do not (and should not) include files outside their module's packages.

Comment: why shouldnt binary distributions include license file?