# How to *install* extra package data using setuptools?

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

This looks an awful lot like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute), but it isn't quite.

The answers to that question cover how to get extra data into a source distribution and binary distribution, but don't actually address how to get package data *installed* when included in a source distribution, or how to get them installed in a wheel file.

Here's an example of what I mean (python 3.7.4):

```
% ls
MANIFEST.in README.txt  foopackage  setup.py    venv

% cat setup.py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='foopackage',
    version='0.0.1',
    description='A Package Full of Foo',
    packages=find_packages(),
    package_data={
        'foopackage': [
            'README.txt',
        ],
    },
    include_package_data=True,
)

% cat MANIFEST.in
include README.txt

% . venv/bin/activate
(venv)
% python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel
[...]
% ls dist
foopackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl foopackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
(venv)
% unzip -v dist/foopackage-0.0.1-py3-none-any.whl| grep README.txt
(venv)
% tar tvzf dist/foopackage-0.0.1.tar.gz| grep README.txt
-rw-r--r--  0 matt   staff       0  8 Nov 17:21 foopackage-0.0.1/README.txt
(venv)
% deactivate

% cd ../foo

% . py/bin/activate
(py)
% pip install ../foopackage/dist/foopackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
Processing ../foopackage/dist/foopackage-0.0.1.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: foopackage
  Found existing installation: foopackage 0.0.1
    Uninstalling foopackage-0.0.1:
      Successfully uninstalled foopackage-0.0.1
  Running setup.py install for foopackage ... done
Successfully installed foopackage-0.0.1
You are using pip version 19.0.3, however version 19.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
(py)
% find . -name README.txt
(py)
%
```

The `README.txt` file isn't included in the `wheel`, and despite being included in the `sdist` file, it is not installed when that package is installed.

I can't seem to find the magic incantation to get setuptools to actually install this file somewhere.  What am I missing?

I should probably point out that the real package I'm building has to be py27 and py34+ compatible, in case that constrains the solution in any way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in

```
package_data={
    'foopackage': [
        'README.txt',
    ],
},
```

With this code you declare that your `foopackage` contains a file `README.txt` (file patterns in `package_data` are treated relative to the packages they belong to). But it is not! The file is in the root folder, not in the `foopackage/` subfolder. This is also the reason why the file is not included into your wheel(s).

By listing the file in `MANIFEST.in` you forced `setuptools` to include the file into source dist but `setuptools` doesn't know what to do with the file — it expects the file to be inside `foopackage/`.

There are 2 ways to fix the problem. 1st, you can declare relative path to the file:

```
package_data={
    'foopackage': [
        '../README.txt',
    ],
},
```

In this case the fill be installed in `foopackage/../README.txt`, that is, in `site-packages/` directory. It could be what you want.

Or not. In which case the right solution is to move the file inside `foopackage/`, fix `MANIFEST.in` and rebuild sdist and wheel(s).