# yaml file not getting copied when installing from setup.py

Tags: python-2.7, setup.py, distutils

for my distutils package the yaml file along with python files is not getting copied

**setup.py**

```
from distutils.core import setup

files = ["*.yaml", "package/*"]

setup(name = "mypackage",
    version = "0.1",
    description = "description",
    author = "Ciasto",
    author_email = "me@email.com",
    packages = ['package'],
    package_data = {'package' : files },
    scripts = ["scripts/runner"],
)
```

this is the project directory structure:

```
$ tree package/
|____
| |______init__.py
| |____command.py
| |____constants.py
| |____controller.py
| |____utils.py
| |____model.py
| |____products.yaml
```

Comment: Relevant answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/7561372

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`package_data` is used to add package's data to eggs (dropped in favor) and wheels (not with `distutils`). You're probably generating source distribution (sdist).

For sdist you need file `MANIFEST.in` (create it besides `setup.py`). In your case it should be enough to have one line in it:

```
include package/*.yaml
```

See the docs at https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/sourcedist.html#specifying-the-files-to-distribute

and

https://packaging.python.org/guides/using-manifest-in/#using-manifest-in

If you're not going to create wheels you can safely remove `files` and `package_data` from `setup.py`.