# create pip-installable single-module package with associated data

Tags: python, module, pip, setuptools

There are many variations on this question I've found, but none seem to address my exact situation where

1. The Python code for the project is contained in a single file
2. There are required data directories that must be included with the installation

I am trying to create a `pip`-installable version of the following Python project, where the project consists of a single Python script `myscript`, plus two different data directories, `data` and `test_data`. `data` contains required data files that are sourced by `myscript.py` at runtime:

```
myscript
|
├── myscript
│   ├── data
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── myscript.py
│   └── test_data
├── LICENSE
├── README.md
└── setup.py
```

I've seen the recommendation to use `py_modules` in `setup.py` for similar issues, but that doesn't seem to allow for inclusion of the data directories upon install with `pip`, and I cannot find documentation that seems to cover this specific case.

I've also seen it recommended to just have users do a `git clone` of the repo instead of using `pip`, but it seems like a usability benefit to offer a way to `pip`-install with all dependencies while correctly adding the script to the PATH in an OS-dependent manner.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a pretty standard Python package. To reproduce your situation, I have the following layout:

```
$ find * -type f
LICENSE
myscript/myscript.py
myscript/data/data_file_1
myscript/test_data/test_data_file_1
myscript/__init__.py
README.md
setup.cfg
setup.py
```

To include the data directories, you can use the `package_data` option in your `setup.cfg` file (which is slowly replacing `setup.py` as the standard way to build Python packages).

We just need a stub `setup.py`:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

Everything else is in `setup.cfg`:

```
[metadata]
name = myscript
version = 1.0
description = An example for glarue
long_description = file: README.md
long_description_content_type = text/markdown
url = https://github.com/larsks/so-example-glarue
author = Lars Kellogg-Stedman
author_email = lars@oddbit.com

[options]
packages = find:

[options.package_data]
myscript = data/*, test_data/*

[options.entry_points]
console_scripts =
    myscript = myscript.myscript:main
```

The key part is the options.package_data` section, which, for each package, lists the glob patterns that should be included as part of the package.

If we build a source distribution from this:

```
$ python setup.py sdist
running sdist
...
Creating tar archive
removing 'myscript-1.0' (and everything under it)
```

We can see that the data files are included in the archive:

```
$ tar tf dist/myscript-1.0.tar.gz
myscript-1.0/
myscript-1.0/PKG-INFO
myscript-1.0/README.md
myscript-1.0/myscript/
myscript-1.0/myscript/__init__.py
myscript-1.0/myscript/data/
myscript-1.0/myscript/data/data_file_1
myscript-1.0/myscript/myscript.py
myscript-1.0/myscript/test_data/
myscript-1.0/myscript/test_data/test_data_file_1
myscript-1.0/myscript.egg-info/
myscript-1.0/myscript.egg-info/PKG-INFO
myscript-1.0/myscript.egg-info/SOURCES.txt
myscript-1.0/myscript.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
myscript-1.0/myscript.egg-info/entry_points.txt
myscript-1.0/myscript.egg-info/top_level.txt
myscript-1.0/setup.cfg
myscript-1.0/setup.py
```

The same holds true if you build a binary distribution with `bdist`.

You can find this entire example online at https://github.com/larsks/so-example-glarue.

Comment: Thank you for the very thorough answer. The solution for me was slightly more complicated, and actually involved info from a much older post from you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14159430/3076552)

Although following your example did result in the package data being included in the `sdist`, installing locally with `pip` did _not_ correctly install the files.

To successfully install the files along with the script, I had to include a `MANIFEST.in` file (as per the answer from gelonida) and a corresponding `include_package_data = True` in `setup.cfg`.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're missing the `MANIFEST.in` file

please look at following mini-project:

Directory structure

```
./MANIFEST.in
./mini/data/f1.txt
./mini/__init__.py
./mini/mini.py
./mini/test_data/f1.txt
./README.md
./setup.py
```

**setup.py**

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name="mini",
      version="0.0.1",
      description="one file pip installable mod",
      long_description="long description",
      long_description_content_type="text/x-rst",
      classifiers=[
            "Development Status :: 3 - Alpha",
      ],
      keywords="sample",
      url="https://github.com/demo",
      author="me",
      author_email="me@my.email.com",
      license="MIT",
      packages=["mini"],
      scripts=[],
      entry_points={
          "console_scripts": [
            "mini = mini.mini:main",
            ]
      },
      install_requires=[],
      extras_require={},
      python_requires=">=3.4",
      setup_requires=[],
      tests_require=[],
      zip_safe=False,
      include_package_data=True,
      )
```

**MANIFEST.in**

```
include README.md
recursive-include mini/data/ *
recursive-include mini/test_data/ *
```

**mini/mini.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

MYPATH = os.path.realpath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

DATA_PATH = os.path.join(MYPATH, "data")
TEST_DATA_PATH = os.path.join(MYPATH, "test_data")

def main():
    print("I am the miniscript")
    with open(os.path.join(DATA_PATH, "f1.txt")) as fin:
        print("DATA FILE", fin.read())
    with open(os.path.join(TEST_DATA_PATH, "f1.txt")) as fin:
        print("TEST DATA FILE", fin.read())

main()
```

Try out with:

```
python -m setup sdist
tar tvfz dist/mini-0.0.1.tar.gz
```