# setuptools including all packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

I am new to python and setup tools. I have following setup.py in root directory which contains several modules. however I wish to only create egg file for one module. Currently it includes all modules. What am I missing here.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name="edl_code",
    version="0.1",
    packages=["scripts_new"]
)
```

Comment: Is there a reason it needs to be in the root directory? Putting it in the desired directory should only create the module inside this directory, no others

Comment: The actual use case is that I need to include some of the packages and sub packages only. root directory has 3 packages. each one has several sub packages. So I need to selectively include some only.

Comment: Does this Thread help you more?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute

Comment: unfortunately no. package_data would include additional files into the package. I guess the workaround for this would be to create a separate directory with only the packages that I need.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Right now it's not possible to deduce the issue from the question.