# Installing test files with pyproject.toml and setuptools

Tags: python, setuptools, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I'm migrating an old python project to the new `pyproject.toml` based system and am having trouble with getting files that are required by tests to install. Inside the `pyproject.toml` I have:

```
[tool.setuptools]
package-data = {"my_pkg_name" = ["tests/*.sdf", "tests/*.urdf", "tests/*.xml", "tests/meshes/*.obj"]}

[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=43.0.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

The tests that are run with `pytest` require the files described under `package-data`. After I build and install the build, the test files are not there. How do I get those files to be installed? [How to include package data with setuptools/distutils?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distutils) may be related, but things have changed, and I would rather not have to create a manifest file.

The project structure looks something like:

```
.
├── LICENSE.txt
├── pyproject.toml
├── README.md
├── src
│   ├── my_pkg_name
│   │   ├── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── ant.xml
    ├── humanoid.xml
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── kuka_iiwa.urdf
    ├── meshes
    │   ├── link_0.obj
    │   ├── link_1.obj
    │   ├── link_2.obj
    │   ├── link_3.obj
    │   ├── link_4.obj
    │   ├── link_5.obj
    │   ├── link_6.obj
    │   └── link_7.obj
    └── test_transform.py
```

The `pyproject.toml` has no specific package discovery related settings.

Comment: Could you include more details about the project's directory structure, and the package discovery related settings in your `pyproject.toml`?

Comment: @Brian I edited the question to include more details about the directory structure; there are no explicit package discovery settings in pyproject.toml.

Comment: Usually I put test files in the source distribution (*sdist*) but not in the build distributions (such as *wheel*). I put my tests in a `test` directory (singular without `s`) and *setuptools* puts them automatically in the *sdist* but not the *wheel*. For additional files (non `*.py`) that should be only in the *sdist*, I use the `MANIFEST.in` file.

Comment: @sinoroc That's interesting that setuptools automatically respects `test` but not `tests`... The https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject has tests under `tests` which I was following

Comment: Yes, I find it strange as well that people do not follow the convention of putting tests in `test`. As far as I know it comes from the old `distutils`. And this behavior is now documented at least here: https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/using-manifest-in/ and here: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/deprecated/distutils/sourcedist.html -- And there is a ticket here: https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject/issues/133 -- See also this: https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/pull/2494

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking more into this, specifically: https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/stable/userguide/datafiles.html#non-package-data-files
my problem is that these files are not part of the default found packages which are just the ones under `src`. It is also not clear whether test files should be installed or not - many projects explicitly exclude test files from installation.

To answer the original question of how to install the test files,
the solution is to make `tests` a package (as I already have above), then specify to find it with setup tools like so:

```
[tool.setuptools.packages.find]
where = ["src", "tests"]

[tool.setuptools.package-data]
"*" = ["*.sdf", "*.urdf", "*.xml", "*.obj"]
```

I believe package-data requires setuptools >= 61 which you can specify like:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0.0", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"
```

Further answering the deeper issue of installed tests failing due to not being able to find test files, the solution in my github actions workflow for doing automated testing on commits was to install in editable mode. Specifically:

```
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        python -m pip install -e .
        python -m pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
```

This is because in my tests, I refer to resource files based on a module's path:

```py
open(os.path.join(cfg.TEST_DIR, "simple_arm.sdf"))
```

in the `cfg` module:

```py
import os

ROOT_DIR = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../../'))
TEST_DIR = os.path.join(ROOT_DIR, 'tests')
```

**EDIT**: A better solution is to reference the test files based on the test script path rather than the package's module's path. This allows us to still test the non-editable installed project. To do this, I have instead

```py
TEST_DIR = os.path.dirname(__file__)
```

in each test script, and replace references to `cfg`.

Comment: I really do not think you should install the tests. Where are they installed anyway? Are they importable as `import tests`? What if all libraries installed their own tests so that they are importable as `import tests`?

Comment: @sinoroc I don't think they get installed. I have the src-layout described in https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/package_discovery.html#src-layout so setuptools should only install the src packages