# Package data not included when installing custom Python package on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, pip, google-cloud-functions, namespace-package

I have a custom namespace package with additional data files that are included via the `package_data` argument of `setuptools.setup`. When I install this custom package for my Google Cloud Function, the data files are not included.

I tried installing the custom package as I normally would, e.g., locally. The data files were present when I installed locally.

I expected Google Cloud Function's `pip` binary to have the same behavior as the standard `pip` binary.

Comment: What the error logs showing. Can you share with the requirement.txt file and the directory structure. Also have you checked with this [Documentation](https://imran-mdkhan197.medium.com/cloud-functions-python-using-local-or-custom-packages-66873832b28c)

Comment: Was the documentation above helpful?

Comment: The error is `FileNotFoundError` because it attempts to load a data file that's not present.

That article you shared is not for [namespace packages](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/packaging-namespace-packages/). My suspicion is that Google has a custom build of `pip` that ignore the `package_data` argument of `setuptools.setup`.

Comment: Have you checked with this [Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/specifying-dependencies-python#python37) and the [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250).