# python including a folder in your distribution package

Tags: python, setuptools

I have a python package structured as below:

```
mypackage
├───build
├───dist
├───mypackage-------> file1.py, file2.py
│   └───templates-->temp.html
└───test
└───MANIFEST.in
└───setup.py
```

what I'm trying to do is to include the templates folder.
Here is the relevant part of my setup.py

```
setup(
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    package_data = {'mypackages': ['templates/*.html']},
```

and here is my MANIFEST.in

```
include mypackage/templates
recursive-include mypackage/ *.html
```

To produce the zip file, I use this command:

```
python setup.py sdist
```

Any ideas why the templates folder does not get included?

Comment: Are you missing an `__init__.py` in the templates folder?
And this: http://www.scotttorborg.com/python-packaging/non-code-files.html

Comment: I do not have `__init__.py` in the template folder. I had tried putting it there but that only causes the folder to be included without the temp.html inside that folder. As for the manifest, I updated my post. It already includes mypackage/templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use MANIFEST.in to specify file to be included.

Duplicate:
[How to include package data with setuptools/distribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7522250/how-to-include-package-data-with-setuptools-distribute)

[2 techniques for including files in a Python distribution: which is better?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968701/2-techniques-for-including-files-in-a-python-distribution-which-is-better/2969087#2969087)

Comment: changing MANIFEST.in to this worked: include mypackage/templates/*

Comment: So why does this not do the same thing: `recursive-include mypackage/ *.html`? That was already in his manifest